# How can I get the values of the next and nearest row that meets my criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using one table, I have to combine values from two separate rows such that the values on the resulting row is dependent on the difference of the values from the two separate ones.

**Given the following sample table:**

```
in_date     out_date    company in_value    out_value
2006-01-01  2006-01-31  ACME    15.03       15.93
2006-01-02  2006-01-31  ACME    14.12       15.85
2006-01-03  2006-01-31  ACME    16.35       14.81
2006-01-04  2006-01-31  ACME    16.06       14.59
2006-01-05  2006-01-31  ACME    16.81       14.07
2006-01-06  2006-01-31  ACME    14.37       16.02
2006-01-07  2006-01-31  ACME    16.36       15.67
2006-01-08  2006-01-31  ACME    15.39       15.01
2006-01-09  2006-01-31  ACME    16.27       15.61
2006-01-10  2006-01-31  ACME    14.45       15.43
2006-01-11  2006-01-31  ACME    16.97       15.45
2006-01-12  2006-01-31  ACME    14.62       15.81
2006-01-13  2006-01-31  ACME    15.11       15.82
2006-01-14  2006-01-31  ACME    14.31       14.34
2006-01-15  2006-01-31  ACME    16.28       15.86
2006-01-16  2006-01-31  ACME    16.40       14.32
2006-01-17  2006-01-31  ACME    14.05       16.94
2006-01-18  2006-01-31  ACME    15.74       14.57
2006-01-19  2006-01-31  ACME    15.79       14.69
2006-01-20  2006-01-31  ACME    15.22       16.14
2006-01-21  2006-01-31  ACME    16.40       16.80
2006-01-22  2006-01-31  ACME    15.22       16.14
2006-01-23  2006-01-31  ACME    16.69       16.79
2006-01-24  2006-01-31  ACME    16.01       14.95
2006-01-25  2006-01-31  ACME    15.28       14.07
2006-01-26  2006-01-31  ACME    15.93       16.47
2006-01-27  2006-01-31  ACME    15.35       14.36
2006-01-28  2006-01-31  ACME    14.92       16.41
2006-01-29  2006-01-31  ACME    15.42       16.04
2006-01-30  2006-01-31  ACME    15.99       15.95
2006-01-31  2006-01-31  ACME    16.75       14.03
```

**I want to get a result like so:**

```
in_date     out_date    target_date company in_value    out_value   target_value
2006-01-01  2006-01-31  2006-01-17  ACME    15.03       14.03       16.94
```

**Wherein:**

- `target_value` is the value of the first row **after** `in_date` such that `out_value - in_value > 1`.
- `target_date` is the respective `in_date` of `target_value`.

**Details:**

I will always have `in_date` and `out_date`. I want to get the first date wherein the `out_value` eventually exceeds `in_value` by 1. In the sample data, if I paid on `2006-01-01`, the first time that I will ever get a profit of 1 or more is on `2006-01-17`.

**Code:**

I pretty much suck at complex queries so I only have the most basic of queries.

```
SELECT in_date, out_date, company, in_value,
        out_value = (SELECT out_value FROM foobar WHERE in_date = '2006-01-31' AND company = 'ACME')
FROM foobar
WHERE in_date = '2006-01-01'
AND out_date = '2006-01-31'
AND company = 'ACME'
```

This, however, gives me all but `target_date` and `target_value`.

**Question:**

How do I get the next and nearest row given that `out_value` at said searched-for row is `1` or more than the `in_value` at my desired `in_date`?

Comment: Depending on your sql server version you could use the LEAD function. Alternatively, you could use a CTE with the ROW_NUMBER function to find the next row.

Comment: the rows are ordered by the 'in_date' right ?

Comment: Yes, the rows are ordered by `in_date`. I was hoping a simpler `JOIN` or subquery would work though. I'm going to check on the LEAD function.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan, what is the version of MSSQL you use?

Comment: In result you have outvalue = 14.03, but I see 14.05       16.94 in test data.
Also doesn't the second row 2006-01-02  2006-01-31  ACME    14.12       15.85 satisfy condition? 15.85 - 14.12 > 1?

Comment: Oh, it's not like that. You have to check the `out_value` of each row versus the `in_value` of the selected `in_date`. In this table, my `in_date` is `2006-01-01`, which has `in_value` of `15.03`. The first row which has an `out_value` that exceeds this by 1 or more is `2006-01-17`, which has an `out_value` of `16.94`.

Comment: Also, I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan, ok I see now. One more question, do you want in result just one row for first row in test data, or you want the results for every row in test data?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: Just the one row. I will always have `in_date`, `out_date`, and `company`. The only thing I need is the specific values needed included in the resultant row. I can always change `in_date` if needed. :)

Comment: For the second time.  Where does the 14.03 in the desired result come from?

Comment: @Blam The `14.03` comes from the `out_value` of the row where `in_date` is the same as `out_date`.

Comment: That is not what the question states "target_date is the respective in_date of target_value".  Answer is only as good as the question.

Comment: @Blam I don't think my wording is incorrect, but if it is, I stand corrected. However, logic is simple. I have `in_date` and `out_date` on hand. I will get `in_value` of `in_date` and `out_value` of `out_date`. Easy enough, I can do that. Next, I need to look for the first `out_value` AFTER given `in_date` whose difference with `in_value` found is 1 or more. When I get this `out_value`, I name it `target_value`. Then, I get the `in_date` of this `target_value` and name it `target_date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TOP syntax , the basic skeleton will be like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
From foobar
Where out_value-1 >= all (Select in_value from foo_bar where in_date='2006-01-01')
order by in_date asc;
```

and you can add the extra AND expression with company name and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just added the required columns. This should be fine

```
SELECT   in_date
       , out_date
       , Target_Date = (SELECT TOP 1 in_date 
                    FROM foobar 
                    where out_date-in_date >1 
                    AND in_date = '2006-01-31' 
                    AND company = 'ACME' 
                    ORDER BY in_date
                    )  
       , company
       , in_value
       , out_value   =  (SELECT TOP 1 out_value 
                     FROM foobar 
                     WHERE in_date = '2006-01-31' 
                     AND company = 'ACME') 
       , Target_Value = (SELECT TOP 1 Out_Value 
                    FROM foobar 
                    where out_date-in_date >1 
                    AND in_date = '2006-01-31' 
                    AND company = 'ACME' 
                    ORDER BY in_date)  

FROM foobar
WHERE in_date = '2006-01-01'
AND out_date = '2006-01-31'
AND company = 'ACME'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `OUTER APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      in_date DATE ,
      out_date DATE ,
      company CHAR(4) ,
      in_value MONEY ,
      out_value MONEY
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( '20060101', '20060131', 'ACME', 15.03, 15.93 ),
        ( '20060102', '20060131', 'ACME', 14.03, 14.93 ),
        ( '20060103', '20060131', 'ACME', 13.03, 13.93 ),
        ( '20060104', '20060131', 'ACME', 12.03, 12.93 ),
        ( '20060105', '20060131', 'ACME', 11.03, 11.93 ),
        ( '20060106', '20060131', 'ACME', 10.03, 15.93 ),
        ( '20060107', '20060131', 'ACME', 09.03, 13.93 ),
        ( '20060108', '20060131', 'ACME', 08.03, 16.93 ),
        ( '20060109', '20060131', 'ACME', 07.03, 17.93 ),
        ( '20060110', '20060131', 'ACME', 06.03, 15.93 )



SELECT  t.* ,
        o.out_value AS target_value ,
        o.in_date AS target_date
FROM    @t t
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                t2.out_value,
                                t2.in_date
                      FROM      @t t2
                      WHERE     t2.in_date > t.in_date
                                AND t2.company = t.company
                                AND t2.out_value > t.in_value + 1
                      ORDER BY  in_date
                    ) o
WHERE   t.in_date = '2006-01-01'
        AND t.out_date = '2006-01-31'
        AND t.company = 'ACME'
```

Output:

```
in_date     out_date    company in_value    out_value   in_value    target_value    target_date
2006-01-01  2006-01-31  ACME    15.03       15.93       8.03        16.93           2006-01-08
```

Also, if you remove `WHERE` clause, you will get desired result for each row.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
(
select t1.*, t2.in_date as t2_in_date, t2.in_value as  t2_in_value,  t2.out_value  as  t2_out_value
     , row_number() order (partition by t1.in_date order by t2.in_date) as rn
  from table t1 
  join tabel t2 
    on t2.in_date   > t1.in_date 
   and t2.out_value > t1.invalue + 1
) as jioned 
where rn = 1
```